# ACF Theme Code Pro doesn't show content on the page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am working with ACF Pro and ACF Theme Code Pro plugins.
It correctly working within admin-panel but not working on site.

Maybe anyone know what i doing incorrectly?

my functions.php

```
add_action( 'acf/init', 'register_about_service_block' );

function register_about_service_block() {

    if ( function_exists( 'acf_register_block_type' ) ) {

        // Register About service block
        acf_register_block_type( array(
            'name'                  => 'about-service',
            'title'                 => __( 'About service' ),
            'description'           => __( 'A custom About service block.' ),
            'category'              => 'formatting',
            'icon'                  => 'layout',
            'keywords'              => array( 'about', 'service' ),
            'post_types'            => array( 'post', 'page' ),
            'mode'                  => 'auto',
            // 'align'              => 'wide',
            'render_template'       => 'template-parts/blocks/about-service.php',
            // 'render_callback'    => 'about_service_block_render_callback',
             'enqueue_style'        => get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/css/services.min.css',
            // 'enqueue_script'     => get_template_directory_uri() . '/template-parts/blocks/about-service/about-service.js',
            // 'enqueue_assets'     => 'about_service_block_enqueue_assets',
        ));
    }
}
```

Plugin genereted code that i can use in my template. I use it in template and it correctly working in admin-panel. It looks like this

[image]

But on my page, where i use this template it not working. Еhe template itself is connected correctly.

function acf_register_block_type must return $block

```
function acf_register_block_type( $block ) {
    
    // Validate block type settings.
    $block = acf_validate_block_type( $block );
    
    // Bail early if already exists.
    if( acf_has_block_type($block['name']) ) {
        return false;
    }
    
    // Add to storage.
    acf_get_store( 'block-types' )->set( $block['name'], $block );
    
    // Register block type in WP.
    if( function_exists('register_block_type') ) {
        register_block_type($block['name'], array(
            'attributes'        => acf_get_block_type_default_attributes(),
            'render_callback'   => 'acf_rendered_block',
        ));
    }
    
    // Register action.
    add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'acf_enqueue_block_assets' );
    
    // Return block.
    return $block;
}
```

Then $block must be use in my template but when i make var_dump($block) i get null. Hence i can't use data by $block in template

Comment: Hi, check this url https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_register_block_type/#examples